# Emberjs classBinding not working on a link-to

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using the `link-to` helper to provide some movement around my application, as usual.  I'm trying to use the `classBinding` property to assign a CSS class, `hide`, to a link.  It's not working, and I'm not sure if it's because I'm misunderstanding context, or what, really.

Here is the relevant part of the template for the link:

```
{{#each SimpleSearchOptions}}
    {{#if isResultsView}}
        {{#link-to 'simpleSearchResults' tagName='li' classNames='chosentab' href=false}}
            <a><span>{{qname}}</span><i class="icon-info-circled helpiconleft"></i></a>
        {{/link-to}}
    {{else}}
    {{#link-to 'simpleSearchOption' this tagName='li' classNames='chosentab' classBinding='hidden:hide' href=false}}
        <a><span>{{qname}}</span><i class="icon-info-circled helpiconleft"></i></a>
    {{/link-to}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And here is part of the model that it is based off of:

```
App.SimpleSearchOptions = [
    {
        "id" : 0,
        "qname": "Application",
        "description": "When you open a door you need one of these applications.",
        "answers": [
            {
                "value" : "*",
                "title": "Any / Unknown",
                "description": "Unknown or variable Applications.",
                "qname": "Application"
            },
            {
                "value" : 1,
                "title": "Building Temperature Control",
                "description": "Prevents warm air from leaving a heated building or cool air from leaving an air-conditioned one.",
                "qname": "Application"
            },
        .....   
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 7,
        "qname": "Heating Power",
        "description": "If a unit is heated using electricity, different amounts of power (in kW) are available.",
        "hidden": true,
        "answers": [
            {
                "value" : "*",
                "title": "Any / Unknown",
                "description": "",
                "qname": "Heating Power"
            },
            {
                "value" : "B",
                "title": "6",
                "description": "",
                "qname": "Heating Power"
            },
            {
                "value" : "C",
                "title": "6.1",
                "description": "",
                "qname": "Heating Power"
            },
           ......
```

That first `{{#if ResultsView}}` works just find when I later dynamically add an element to the `SimpleSearchOptions` array.  Why does the `classBinding='hidden:hide'` not work, then?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `classNameBindings`

```
{{link-to 'Click to see the pretty colors!' 'colors' classNameBindings="isGreen:green"}}
```

[Simple isGreen Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/193/edit)

Comment: Sorry for the long time between replies - I have tried changing it to classNameBindings and it does not work, either.